# Is there a way in Visual Basic to add items from a ListView1 to a ListView2?

Tags: vb.net

did not know how to exactly ask the title question. i have a listview1 box with 2 columns. first column has players name and second column has players scores. listview2 box has the players name and scores from another game. i need to add the score from listview1 to listview2 to give a grand total score of both games and to not add the players name twice but just add the total scores together and have the grand total in listview2. i have tried adding the scores subitems but had no luck. i also have tried clone

```
ListView2.Items.Add(ListView1.Items(0).Clone())
```

but didnt work to add what i need.

anyone have any ideas the best way to do this?
thank you in advanced.

Comment: I suggest using an intermediate POCO-based "model" (or "view model") to represent the information you intend to display and then using WinForm's DataBinding features to display it, instead of manipulating `ListBox.Items` directly.

Comment: You don't need luck to add a few numbers.  You need to declare a variable and initialise it to zero, then loop through the items you want to add and add each value to the running total.  At the end of that, your variable contains the total.  It works the exact same way as if you were, for instance, adding numbers on physical pages with a calculator.  Just keep in mind that a `ListView` contains `Strings`, so you need to convert them to numbers in order to add them as numbers.

Comment: Yes you really shouldn't think in terms of user interface. ListBoxes, buttons, etc. use some kind of observable collection, mvvm and linq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a button to transfer data from Listbox 1 to Listbox 2

If you want to transfer ALL items from Listbox 1 to Listbox 2 then you should use 'FOR NEXT LOOP'

Example:

```
Listbox2.Items.Clear() Clear first the data in ListBox 2

then add this loop assuming you want to select all data

For i = 0 To Listbox1.Items.Count - 1

    Listbox2.Items.Add(Listbox1.Items(i).ToString)

Next
```